# Regex for Italian fiscal code, with uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression for the Italian fiscal code which works.

`^([A-Za-z]{6}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[abcdehlmprstABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Za-z]{1})$|([0-9]{11})$`

I've tried this one.

`^([A-Z]{6}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[ABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Z]{1})$|([0-9]{11})$`

It works as I want,[here](https://regex101.com/r/sC9dsl/1) but it is case insensitive in *Google App Maker*
and also matching lowercase letters while I want to **match only uppercase letters**.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want a regular expression for Italian fiscal code with letter uppercase only..

Comment: Then remove the lowercase letters from the regex pattern.

Comment: I tried it, It stops to work, I'm using in google app-maker environment.

Comment: Can you show us some sample fiscal codes?

Comment: this is from wikipedia - MLLSNT82P65Z404U

Comment: Your pattern is already working, [check the demo](https://regex101.com/r/dYNfGw/1).

Comment: Yes, It works but It shouldn't work for lower case letters in the fiscal code...

Comment: Have you tried using regex's case insensitive flag (`i`)?

Comment: I want to it to be case sensitive :) allow the only uppercase...

Comment: As said above, remove the small letters: `^([A-Z]{6}[0-9lLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[ABCDEHLMPRST][0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Z][0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Z]|[0-9]{11})$` If this doesn't work, show us some cases that don't work.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves my problem...

```
^([A-Z]{6}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[ABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Z]{1})$|([0-9]{11})$
```

[demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/sC9dsl/1)

*there was some temporary problem in App Maker environment or just some confusion.*

Answer (score 8):

While the accepted answer may be ok for a quick check it's still far from complete and it will let through some incorrect codes.

This [blog post](http://blog.marketto.it/2016/01/regex-validazione-codice-fiscale-con-omocodia/) (in italian) describes what can be done with regular expression validation and how. I am not the author of the blog post, so all credits should go to him.

Long story short the result is:

```
/^(?:[A-Z][AEIOU][AEIOUX]|[AEIOU]X{2}|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}[A-Z]){2}(?:[\dLMNP-V]{2}(?:[A-EHLMPR-T](?:[04LQ][1-9MNP-V]|[15MR][\dLMNP-V]|[26NS][0-8LMNP-U])|[DHPS][37PT][0L]|[ACELMRT][37PT][01LM]|[AC-EHLMPR-T][26NS][9V])|(?:[02468LNQSU][048LQU]|[13579MPRTV][26NS])B[26NS][9V])(?:[A-MZ][1-9MNP-V][\dLMNP-V]{2}|[A-M][0L](?:[1-9MNP-V][\dLMNP-V]|[0L][1-9MNP-V]))[A-Z]$/i
```

This takes into account almost all rules, probably all rules that can be checked with a regular expression.

To create a full validation a code function will be required: the last 5 charachters of the fiscal codes are composed by a birthplace ID (4 char) and a CRC (1 char). Checking for the existence of the birthplace ID and applying the CRC calculation will complete the process.

Note: I haven't completely verified all possible cases of fiscal codes but the regular expression has solved all validation problems I had. Also remember that even if you create a perfect validation function it still can be a fake, but formally correct, fiscal code.